# How to solve an error in using simplify() method in R?

Tags: r, derivative, simplify

It's the first time I try to calculate an expression's derivative using R. I have tried the following code:

```
library(Ryacas)                       # open the Ryacas package.
f <- expression(asin(2*x/(1 + x^2)))  # insert the expression.
d <- D(f, 'x')                        # find the expression's derivative.
print(d)                              # print the derivative of f.
simple_d <- simplify(d)               # make the mathematical expression of the derivative simpler.
print(simple_d)                       # print the simply expressed derivative of f.
```

And I received the following error message about the usage of the `simplify()` method.

```
Error in UseMethod("simplify") : 
  no applicable method for 'simplify' applied to an object of class "call"
```

Any ideas on this ? How should I properly use `simplify()` method on an expression like `d` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ryacas0 as shown:

```
library(Ryacas0)                   
x <- Sym("x")
f <- asin(2*x/(1 + x^2))
d <- deriv(f, x)                   
d                             
Simplify(d)
```

or Ryacas like this:

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- ysym("x")
f <- asin(2*x/(1 + x^2))
d <- deriv(f, x)
d
simplify(d)
```

Comment: Thank you! What Sym (in Ryacas0) and ysym (in Ryacas) stand for?

Comment: `?Sym` and `?ysym`